# Remove Popover View Controller -swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a modally presented view controller. And I have a button which I am trying to get to remove this View Controller. I have not used a storyboard, did the whole thing programatically.

Here is where I add the modal view controller:

```
@objc func addNewReminderr()  {
    addReminderViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(addReminderViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

What I am trying to do is remove the modal view controller by pressing a button from the previous view controller which the new view controller resides on top of. (The button from the previous VC is of course not completely covered by the new VC and remains visible to the user).

The issue is that the app cannot detect the user's tap of the button which I want to use to remove the modal view controller.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of presenting the view controller, add it's view as a subview.

```
let popOverVC: PopUpViewController = PopUpViewController(nibName: "PopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
popOverVC.type = popupType
if message != nil {popOverVC.errorMessage.text = message}
if title != nil {popOverVC.errorTitle.text = title}
parent.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = parent.view.frame
parent.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)
```

and since it is a subview, you can access the button on the parent view